# Selecting a specific children element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select specific children elements from the $el.html, there are two types of children elements, one with `<span>....</span>`, the other has a span class `<span class = "special">..</span>` for example:

```
var orig = $(".example").html()
    ,$el = $(".example")
    ,text = $.trim($el.text())
    ,words = text.split(" ")
    ,html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === "senior")
    html += "<span class='special'>" + words[i] + ((i+1) === words.length ? "" : " ") + "</span>";
    else
        html += "<span>" + words[i] + ((i+1) === words.length ? "" : " ") + "</span>";
   };
$el.html(html).children().hide().each(function(i){
 // if $('span.special')
  $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn(700);
 // else (normal span)
  $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn(900);
}).promise().done(function(){
       $('.example:first').html(orig)
    })
```

How can I tell the difference between the spans with and without the class within my 'each' call?

> the working demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/15/

Comment: So: what is the question? They ARE fading in one after another.

Comment: And fading in rather well.. Good demo there..

Comment: i just wanna know how i can distgunish between the two spans on each(), so i can do something different, this is just simple example im working.

Comment: @techfoobar Good demo but absolutely awful question.

Comment: thanks @AnthonyGrist , im sure we can do without the remarks, but thier you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
$el.html(html).children().hide().each(function(i){
  if($(this).hasClass('special'))
      $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn(700);
  else
      $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn(900); 
}).promise().done(function(){
       $('.example:first').html(orig)
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/16/)

However, if you only want to fade in the `.special` elements use

```
$el.html(html).children('.special').hide().each(function(i){
  if($(this).hasClass('special'))
      $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn(700);
}).promise().done(function(){
       $('.example:first').html(orig)
});
```

instead (see [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/17/)).

Comment: Alternately, you can use `if ($(this).is(".special")) {...}` which in some circumstances is more readable.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/CVu6U/)